# Problem to move a MC on foreground

Tags: actionscript-3

i've a problem to a set a different child index of a Movieclip. This is the code:

```
function processMusica():void
{

    var loadStatus:int=0
    var lastHeight:int=0

    for (var m=0; m < myXML.BLADE[sup].child("brano").length(); m++)
    {
       var titolobrano:TextField=new TextField  
       bladearray[sup].contenitore.addChild(titolobrano)
       titolobrano.text=myXML.BLADE[sup].brano[loadStatus].titolo

       lastHeight=titolobrano.height
       titolobrano.doubleClickEnabled=true
       titolobrano.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, riproducibrano)
       loadStatus+=1   
    }

    if (isPlaying==false)
    {
       var riproduzioneDetails:MovieClip=new MovieClip
       riproduzioneDetails.name="riproduzioneDetails"
       var artista:TextField=new TextField
       artista.name="artista"
       bladearray[sup].contenitore.addChild(riproduzioneDetails)
       riproduzioneDetails.x=475
       riproduzioneDetails.addChild(artista)

    }
    setChildIndex(bladearray[sup].contenitore.riproduzioneDetails, bladearray[sup].contenitore.numChildren-1) //<------ PROBLEM HERE!
```

I want to move "riproduzioneDetails" MC on foreground, but when i attempt to launch application, it give me this error: **TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null**

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potential problems, but it is hard to say because all the variables are not declared in your code. There may be a problem with your test condition:

```
if (isPlaying==false)
{
  ...
}
```

If "isPlaying" is true, your object "riproduzioneDetails" is never created, so of course it will be null. You have to create your object outside the "if" condition, before testing "isPlaying".

Another potential problem is the way you access your object, with "bladearray[sup].contenitore.riproduzioneDetails". As you used the "addChild" method to store your object, there should logically be a kind of "getChild" method. For instance,

```
setChildIndex(bladearray[sup].contenitore.getChildByName("riproduzioneDetails"),bladearray[sup].contenitore.numChildren-1)
```

... may be better.

Comment: Ok, i removed the condition and wrote as you said

setChildIndex(bladearray[sup].contenitore.getChildByName("riproduzioneDetails"),bladearray[sup].contenitore.numChildren-1)


but now it give me error ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller error - AS

Comment: Read carefuly the error :-) Here, you apply "setChildIndex" to the default "this" object, but "this" do not have "riproduzioneDetails". You have to apply your "setChildIndex" method on your "contenitore", as it is "contenitore" who owns "riproduzioneDetails". You will have to check, but I thinkg that if you write bladearray[sup].contenitore.setChildIndex(bladearray[sup].contenitore.getChildByName("riproduzioneDetails"),‌​bladearray[sup].contenitore.numChildren-1) it should be better.

Comment: ok just wrote what you said and... WORKS!
I thought that setChildIndex don't need any parameter ahead it and it need all parameters inside brackets

thanks

EDIT: i just discovered that i can write bladearray[sup].contenitore.setChildIndex(riproduzioneDetails, bladearray[sup].contenitore.numChildren-1) too